# Can't find where white border is coming from

Tags: css, carousel, slick.js, splidejs

I've been trying to get rid of the white border that shows up on the left and right of the main product images for hours! Pulling my hair out. Not sure if it's Splide slider or coming from somewhere else.

https://serpentforge.com/collections/skull-rings/products/sugar-skull-1

[image]

[image]

Comment: i can't see the border in the website .maybe it's a browser related problem

Comment: It looks like thats another image inside of the carousel.

Comment: looks like its coming from youtube vids.